# Android list of files counting

Tags: android, performance, listview

I have a performance question. I have a file list adapter, where I list files for current directory.
But, when it comes to counting number of files for each subdirectory (I do it in getView() method) the performance drops. Anyone know how to deal with this problem ? Because, when I tested the ES File explorer, their manager haven't got any issues with number of files.

Comment: Just don't do it on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getView()` displays things on screen, it's not the right place to prepare for data. You may start separate threads to get file lists of sub folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any code snippet how to do this ?